# ServiceBase.Run, why can't I catch it's exceptions, or react to them in some other way?

Tags: c#, exception, windows-services, try-catch

I'm calling the following from my entry point static main method:

```
    try { ServiceBase.Run(new MonitorSer()); }
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName); }
```

MonitorSer is an instance of:

```
class MonitorSer : ServiceBase {
```

and the entry main method is a member of my class:

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class WindowsServiceInstaller : Installer {
```

I've had good results catching exceptions for debugging but sometimes they seem to find their own way around my traps, as in this case.

I get a windows box flash up telling me I need to install using installutil when what I really want is to find the name of this process and call it again with the -i switch which I have wired up to make it install intself (credit to those here who contributed/recycled that code).

What makes this more frustrating is that if I set breakpoints upto (or on) the call to ServiceBase.Run, it will fail silently and I am left with the blinking console.

**UPDATE**

```
    static void Install(bool undo, string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(undo ? "uninstalling" : "installing");
            using (AssemblyInstaller inst = new AssemblyInstaller(typeof(MonitorSer).Assembly, args))
            {
                IDictionary state = new Hashtable();
                inst.UseNewContext = true;
                try
                {
                    if (undo) inst.Uninstall(state);
                    else
                    {
                        inst.Install(state);
                        inst.Commit(state);
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    try
                    {
                        inst.Rollback(state);
                    }
                    catch { }
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I clumped the entry point here so I could call the above function, I'll try moving that to another class and setting the entry point there, but I know I can make this entry point (that you, Dmitry, deny) work by calling itself with the appropriate argument to install- which only the BaseService class can do- correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The ServiceBase.OnStart() method is called from code that catches exceptions and logs them in the Windows event log.  Pretty important it works this way, there's a big chunk of operating system code in between that can't by unwound by an exception (StartServiceCtrlDispatcher)

Comment: @Hans, it can't but I can recover in my finally clause. Tell me I'm the baddest. Yep, I had some other exceptions flutter by my inner catches when I tried calling onstart directly (IIRC).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class WindowsServiceInstaller : Installer
```

Is not your entry point. This will get called once when you install your service using InstallUtil.exe. Entry point can be specified in the project properties and it usually defaults to `Program.Main`. You should not be starting your service from Installer class.

CLR will let you know of unhandled exceptions if you subscribe to this event:

```
static void Main() {
    ...
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException 
                                      += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
    ...
}

private static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(
                                                 Object sender, 
                                                 UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) {

    if (e != null && e.ExceptionObject != null) {
        // log exception:
    }
}
```

> This event provides notification of uncaught exceptions. It allows the
>   application to log information about the exception before the system
>   default handler reports the exception to the user and terminates the application
>   ...
>   Starting with the .NET Framework version 4, this event is not raised
>   for exceptions that corrupt the state of the process, such as stack
>   overflows or access violations, unless the event handler is
>   security-critical and has the
>   HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute attribute.
>   application.

Another place where you might want to log exceptions in windows service (because .NET/SCM will swallow startup exceptions):

```
protected override void OnStart(String[] args) {
    try {

    } catch(Exception e) {
        // log exception:
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Error 4 'MonitorService.WindowsServiceInstaller.CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object, System.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type' In response to next comment, thanks that fixed the IDE for me.

Comment: Unless I need to refactor entry point to a new class. I am missing something, your code caught nothing to log.

Comment: You read my mind, this is where it gets to (and can or cannot set a flag) so now it is fixed and can install itself, on that first, fraught, execution.